# Modelling impact of study materials towards students giving correct answers

Tags: bayesian, treatment-effect

I am new to Bayesian statistics. I have a basic idea about priors, posteriors and likelihood. I have a problem to model using bayesian statistics, and apply using python. ( this is a side project i do understand Bayesian statistics)

I have a sequential data set of students attempting questions, [0,1,1,0,0,m,1,1,0,m,0,1].

0 - wrong answer ,1 - correct answer , m- student refer study material.

I want to model the impact of study materials(probability of giving a correct answer after referring the study materials)

M - referring study material after giving a wrong answer

T - Giving a correct answer

P(T |M) =P(M|T) xP(T) / P(M) -> is this the correct approach

is it correct if I calculate P (T) diving correct answer by total attempts or do I need to use beta(5,5) distribution If i should use beta distribution ,how to build the model .

Again what I am trying to achieve is, students can refer study materials if they give a wrong answer and re try the question. i want to calculate the probability of giving the correct answer after referring the study materials